# How to refresh kendo grid from another angular controller controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an Angular page which has a grid. Now, I have a modal on the page with its own separate controller. When modal is open, I end up adding one more row into the original data source of the grid. Now, I want to close the modal and then see the grid refreshed.

I am not able to do so because modal and the hostpage(the page with the grid) have two separate controllers. How can I communicate to the Home Controller from Modal controller that the source has been updated and now it is time to refresh?

Comment: Use `service` or `rootScope`.

Comment: what is name of your modal component? do you use ngDialog?

Comment: Just throw event and catch it in parent controller